# Blender 2.8 lookdev shortcut

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shortcut

Hi need little help pls I just downloaded blender to start learning it and this is the first tutorial I work on. (tut) on the right he pressed Z and chose (lookdev) I did the same (on the left image) but I got a totally different result so can someone help pls so I can get the same results or know where the problem come from..

This is the tutorial results..
[image]

This is my results..
[image]

Comment: I can see now that Lookdev is already activated in 3D viewport in your image, look at the top right corner in your seen, in order to make your seen look like the tutorial's, you need to enable bloom in Render panel.

Comment: thanks so much George problem solved